# What causes 403 -Forbidden error on this Ajax call

Tags: php, ajax

I am calling a php file with Ajax, but I receive a 403 error when I do so.
What I have determined so far:

Other Ajax calls in the same calling file work fine. The files they
   call are in the same directory as the problem file, so I have ruled
   out permissions problems. I have carefully reentered the path
   db_ajax/regDupAjax.php

The data being sent does not appear to break
   any rules (it is a simple JSON stringified string 
   {"list":["17761","17762"],"chosen":"17762"} )

The php file is simple and straightforward and runs perfectly if called from my browser with the test values uncommented:

```
session_start;
$list= $rec = $selected = $alist = '';
$json = $_REQUEST['jFormData'];
//test values
//$json = '{"list":["17761","17762"],"chosen":"none"}';
$data = json_decode($json, true);

$alist = $data['list'];
include_once('dbaccessWebsite.php');
//
//   Remove the valid registration from the array
//
if($selected !='none'){
    $alist = array_diff($alist, [$selected]);
}
//
//   Loop to delete records from the database
//
foreach($alist as $key=>$recID){
   $rec = $fm->getRecordById('w_ClassMemberData', $recID);
   echo $recID . '<br>';
       $rec->delete();
}

?>
```

- The ajax call appears to be correct:

```
             $.ajax({
                     url         : 'db_ajax/regDupAjax.php', // the url where we want to POST
                     type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
                     data        : jFormData, // our data object
                     contentType: 'json',
                 });
```

What have I overlooked?